# My simple php class not working

Tags: php, class, oop

I wrote a simple class. but its not working. Something is wrong. can't find error line

```
class Host
{
    public $scheme;
    public $hostname;
    public $www;

    function __construct(string $scheme,string $hostname,string $www)
    {
       $this->scheme = $scheme;
       $this->hostname = $hostname;
       $this->www = $www;
    }

    public function get_URL()
    {
       return $this->scheme.'://'.$this->www.$this->hostname;
    }
 }

 $site = new Host('https','google.com','www');
 echo $site->get_URL();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong output?

Comment: no i get nothing whitepage

Comment: scalar type hinting? Not yet supported in PHP (unless you're already running [PHP7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5))

Comment: Note also that your get_url() method will return `https://wwwgoogle.com` and not `https://www.google.com`

Comment: wow okay. I understood. Type hints cannot be used with scalar types such as int or string.

Comment: Nope, you can currently only type-hint classes/interfaces or `array`; though that will be changing in PHP7, which will allow you to type-hint `int`, `float`, `string` and `bool`

Comment: Use error reporting. Add this to the top of files: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use type hints with scalar values ( in you case `string` - check the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php))

Change your constructor in this way:

```
public function __construct($scheme, $hostname, $www)
{
    $this->scheme = $scheme;
    $this->hostname = $hostname;
    $this->www = $www;
}
```

and it should work